# What will this declaration line become after the program has passed through the C pre-processor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

suppose we have the following line at the top of the program

```
#define MAXNAME = 32;
```

and then the declaration

```
char name[MAXNAME];
```

in the program. What will this declaration line become after the program has passed
through the C pre-processor?

Comment: Run it through the preprocessor and check yourself.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/SRjxxn

Comment: Is this an assignment or homework question?

Comment: Supposed.... did you checked yourself?

Answer (score 2):

`#define` macros perform direct text substitution.  So after the preprocessor runs your declaration will look like this:

```
char name[= 32;];
```

Which is invalid.  You probably want:

```
#define MAXNAME 32
```

Which will give you:

```
char name[32];
```